# Automate multiple repetitive ArcGIS 10.2 Table Relates?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, relates

I have a situation where multiple users will be creating many file gdb's in ArcGIS 10.2 using just the basic license.  The data format is standardized and will have a feature layer with point data and a set number of fields and then many pre-generated tables of data that summarize the points.  For example a table with counts for a specific field value, or counts for a specific category of data based on a field in the points layer.  The current workflow is then to manually create table relates so that the user can highlight summary data and then have that highlight the relevant records in the points data.

As the data will always have the same fields (only the data changes) and the summaries will always be the same I'd like to automate the building of the table relates instead of the user having to go in and do them all by hand.  The desired result being that the user gets that interactive selection that comes with a table relate.

After looking around for possible solutions I've found several that are similar...for example using joins, or using the [Make Table View](http://www.maprantala.com/2010/08/11/trying-to-perform-relate-in-model-builder/) to 'relate' data...but none of them address the interactive selection piece which is what I want.

This is the Basic License so Relationship Classes in the gdb are not an option.  It looks like ArcGIS Pro adds the functionality in ArcPy as [arcpy.AddRelate_management](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-relate.htm) but that same feature is not available in 10.2.

I'm open to ArcPy, the ModelBuilder or some other solution.